# Error 0xc000007b: Trying to run C++ .exe file compiled as Release x86 on a computer without VS

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015, and trying to compile a C++ code in Release mode, x86. My operating system is Windows 10, 64-bit OS and x64-based processor.

After it builds, if I run the .exe file from my laptop, it works perfectly fine. However, if I transfer everything in the Release folder to another computer (Windows 8) - no Visual Studio - along with two DLL files (pthreadVC2.dll and ucrtbased.dll), it gives me error 0xc000007b: the application was unable to start.

I've tried statically linking the libraries, but that didn't help. If I run the Dependency Walker, it says that the file - on my computer - has errors, and gives a log of what's wrong, which I cannot understand:

> Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing
>   export function in an implicitly dependent module. 
>   Error: Modules with different CPU types were found. 
>   Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.

I looked around on this website, and apparently it means that 64-bit DLLs are being loaded and I should change that from `Path`. How do I do that? And why doesn't it work on the other computer, which has the same processor? I installed the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, but that did nothing.

Another question: The code uses many external headers. Do I have to export them to the other machine as well? Aren't they compiled as a LIB File?

I'm sorry if I sound clueless, but I rarely write applications using Visual Studio. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't use VS all that much anymore, but a thing to ask is if you changed your build target. I seem to remember Windows 10 going back to NT, while 8 was their terrible experiment with RT. You may need to re-release it. Not an answer because it could well be wrong, just something to try.

Comment: @Jacob, yes, you are very wrong, as you suspected. Encouraging more trial and error thrashing around is not constructive.

Comment: You are lacking knowledge here. Thrashing around at random without knowledge isn't going to do much good. You need to understand your dependencies. You need to go back to basics. You've possibly mis-interpreted Dependency Walker's output. Again that's down to a knowledge defecit. Don't expect a silver bullet. You'll need to gain the missing knowledge.

Comment: Crystal ball says that you copied the wrong DLL(s).  Copy them from c:\windows\syswow64, not c:\windows\system32.  And only ever deploy the Release build of your program, your Debug build can only work properly on a machine that has VS installed.

Answer (score 1):

That error code is an `NTSTATUS` code, specifically `STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT`. That usually means that the loader is finding 64 bit modules rather than 32 bit modules. Exactly which modules are the wrong bitness is hard for us to tell. Running the startup under Dependency Walker's profile mode would reveal all.

You do really need to get a clear handle on what dependencies your program has. You have specific dependencies related to your program that go beyond the normal MSVC runtime dependency. Only you can know what your dependencies are. A tool like Dependency Walker can help you understand them, but make sure your understanding is solid. Try not to use trial and error to resolve this.